# Alexa-hosted skill error when using "ask new"

Tags: git, command-line-interface, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

Spent a few hours on this now so time to ask for help. Trying to install Alexa ASK CLI on Windows 10.

NPM v5.5.1
Node v8.9.1
Git git version 2.28.0.windows.1

Ran "ask configure" and set up profile fine.

When i run "ask new" it gets to "- Cloning Alexa Hosted Skill..." the throws the following error:

```
throw new CLiError(`${ex}`);
            

CliError: Error: Command failed: git fetch --all --quiet
C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/4c375da4- 
810d-4c16-b07e-0f5851bf72aa': No such file or directory
error: Could not fetch origin

at GitClient._execCommands (C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\clients\git-client.js:238:23)
at GitClient.fetchAll (C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\clients\git-client.js:98:14)
at _gitCloneWorkflow (C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\controllers\hosted-skill-controller\clone-flow.js:83:15)
at Object.cloneProjectFromGit (C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\controllers\hosted-skill-controller\clone-flow.js:60:5)
at getHostedSkillMetadata (C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\controllers\hosted-skill-controller\index.js:66:23)
at smapiClient.skill.alexaHosted.getAlexaHostedSkillMetadata (C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\controllers\hosted-skill-controller\index.js:102:13)
at _normalizeSmapiResponse (C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\clients\smapi-client\index.js:169:21)
at _normalizeSmapiResponse (C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\clients\smapi-client\index.js:189:5)
at httpClient.request (C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\clients\smapi-client\index.js:168:17)
at Request.requestLib [as _callback] (C:\Users\Edd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\clients\http-client.js:62:16)'''
```

Ive tried reinstalling NPM, Node, Git, resetting "ask configure", changing GIT install options and everything else I can think of.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded node to 12.18.0 and NPM to 6.14.4 and worked.